# Chrome detects unexptected token ":" even though it isn't there

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, google-chrome

I try to get JSON data from google distancematrix API with this jQuery code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?units=imperial&origins=Washington,DC&destinations=New+York+City,NY&key=AIzaSyC1YPi3w46cOyrkUa8s0vR9QHzeoQCoum4";
        $.ajax({
          type: "GET",
          url: url,
          dataType: "json",
          jsonpCallback: "results"
        })

        function results(data) {
            console.log("data" + data);
        } 
    });
</script>
```

If I take a look at the console of my browser (Google Chrome), I get this error message:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

[image]

If I click on that JSON file I get "Nothing to preview".

Edit:

I see this reply in my network tab:

[image]

The strange thing is that the correct JSON Response is sent to my browser:

[image]

Comment: please can you use `console.log("data:", data);` and see what it logs? alert may only display [object Object]

Comment: Are you sure that's not the response triggering the error?  You sure you're sending back well formed JSON? What does the response look like in your network tab, does it fire off at all?

Comment: You're getting a `JSON ` response since the endpoint isn't returning `JSONP`. In your URL, the endpoint is also specified as `json` right before query params. I doubt that you can get this to work using `JSONP` (Google won't return it that is)

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll still end up running into CORS issues. I recommend approaching it differently by utilizing Google API's docs. It is fairly easy, gives you far more options and works better:

```js
(function($){

function init(){
var origin = 'Greenwich, England';
var destination = 'Stockholm, Sweden';

var service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();
service.getDistanceMatrix(
  {
    origins: [origin],
    destinations: [destination],
    travelMode: 'DRIVING'
  }, callback);

function callback(response, status) {
  // See Parsing the Results for
  // the basics of a callback function.
 
 console.log(response);
}
};
 
$(window).ready(function(){
 init();
});
})(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script async defer
src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=yourkey">
</script>
```

Fiddle [working fiddle without key](https://jsfiddle.net/rvam7ys7/2/)

**EDIT**

Google's response will either be in `JSON` or `XML`. To get a `JSONP` response, Google would need to support that response for your endpoint, which it doesn't. Having an API key does not seem to get around the CORS issue meaning a request for `JSON` data will result in "No Access Control Headers Present" error.

From Docs: *"These web services use HTTP requests to specific URLs, passing URL parameters as arguments to the services. Generally, these services return data in the HTTP request as either JSON or XML for parsing and/or processing by your application."*

See [Google Maps API Docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/web-services/overview)

Comment: This exercise is for a lecture and it is prohibited to use Google Libraries to handle the JSON data (I don't understand why but thats how it is).

Comment: Google won't arbitrarily respond with `jsonp` to a `json` request (see endpoint: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json). You can try to force that response and you'll get a response (200) but you can't do anything with it. There are various solutions here but your approach as is, will always run into CORS. I hate pointless lecture exercises.

Answer (score -1):

It is a sneaky one and it did take me a few gueses:

```
//Change this:
dataType: "jsonp",
// to this:
dataType: "json",
```

Might be relevent ***how*** I found it so you can do it next time (I did all this in my console, but in a script/file would work as well):

- First I just entered the url -> no error, so no weird url, or other funky stuff
- Then just the `results` function -> still no errors. Now we know its in the ajax call.
- Entered the ajax function into my editor like this:

  - First all of it -> I got the error
  - Now just the AJAX function with the TYPE and URL -> no error
  - Added the dataType back in -> the error.
  - Removed the dataType and added the callback -> no error
  - Now we know it *must* be the dataType line
- Copied that sentence to my editor and enlarged the font to huge

  - All characters looked fine, no funky quotes.
  - Retyped the whole line by hand (no copy/past) and tried that -> Error
  - Now we know it's either the incorrect key, or incorect value
- Open documentation, see how to spell it (capital T, for sure?) -> correct
- Open documentation, see correct values -> Wait, there is no JSONP
- Change code, "jsonp" -> "json" -> working code!

> Cross-domain "json" requests are converted to "jsonp"

So jquery does that for you internally.

Comment: Can you Show my your full html Code please? I edited my question, maybe this additional Information helps you.

Comment: I used your js, just copied it to my console. All I changed, was the P, thats it. Then I got a reponse back which said "unvailid token"

Comment: Then you get the same error as me. It Looks like Google Chrome doesn't know how to Interpret the json data and detects a `:` as invalid token. Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: I doubt the data is incorrect, all panic would brake loose if that were the case. If this doesnt fix it, i dont know. taht worked for me

Comment: You just said that you get the error `invalid token` so how did that fix it for you if you get an error?

Comment: I've explained my steps in my answer. If those dont help, Im sorry, I cant help

Comment: This solution won't work. The response has to be `jsonp` which is not the case here. Google is STILL responding with `json` forcing CORS.